# How to determine which version of SQL Server is running using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help using T-SQL to figure-out the version of SQL Server running and execute different code sets based on weather SQL Server 2000 or Sql Server 2008 is running.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT @@VERSION?
```

Or one of the [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) options?

Answer (score 6):

Just query the database - there is a [`@@VERSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177512.aspx) property:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

> Returns version, processor architecture, build date, and operating system for the current installation of SQL Server.

As mentioned on the page, since all of this data is returned in one varchar, you can use the [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) function to  retrieve only the version:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
```

Comment: That's an ugly string to deal with programatically.

Answer (score 6):

```
 SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')
       , SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')
       , SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

Answer (score 5):

@@VERSION / SERVERPROPERTY

But you should also check

```
exec sp_dbcmptlevel 'dbname'
```

To ensure a certain feature works at the database's compatibility level.

Comment: Good thinking about sp_dbcmptlevel. This matters more in some cases

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')
```

The digits before the first period will give you the major version: 10 = 2008, 9 = 2005, 8 = 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Use to get the server SQL version:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
GO
```

Or for a more verbose command

```
SELECT @@VERSION
GO
```

Also in [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions) you can find a list of the releases's version numbers

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC[MASTER].SYS.[XP_MSVER]--To  get  the  server version
```